# Observe any kind of JS data structure deeply

Tags: javascript, observable

I just struggled around to find a generic solution to watch or observe a data structure within JavaScript.There are multiple ways to do so:

1. Implement your own observable data structure objects e.g.: `ObservableList`.
2. Also polling of the attributes can be used to detect changes. There is even a framework based on polling. See here: [Watch.JS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS)
3. Overwrite the set method of an attribute with the following code: `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'text', { set: function(t) { this.text = t; console.log('changed') } });`: [Mozilla API - overwrite setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Defining_a_setter_on_existing_objects_using_defineProperty). So if someone set an attribute of an object it is possible to emit an event or call a function if someone does `obj.text = 'Hallo'`.
4. There was `Object.observe(obj, callback)`, but this does not work in most browsers anymore.
5. There is `obj.watch('text', callback)`, but this does only work in Gecko browsers.

I personally prefer the third method; overwriting the setter method of an attribute. But this way has a small problem. I can not watch array modifications (`obj.arr[2]='What?'`). Maybe there are other things that does not work well I haven't figured out yet.

Another problem I see here is that there is actually no framework that just abstracts everything for me. And there is no framework that deeply watches data structures for me, like e.g.: object with arrays with objects.

Or there is such a framework but I didn't find it.

Comment: Have you taken a look a RxJS?

Comment: I just looked at it, but it seems that RxJS is using their own implementation of data structures if I get this correct (see 1.)?

Comment: Yes, and for Objects, I think under the hood they implement Object.observe...

Comment: Object.observe is not supported by chrome. I don't think so. I currently write a framework (React inspired) and I want to support native JS objects to be watched for updating the UI.

Comment: Have you played around with [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) yet? It's not fully supported cross-browser but I'm not sure what your use-case is - it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: That looks very intereseting. I will have a look at this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this deep observable structure?

Comment: I just want to write a framework for clean web developement like React/Angular with a storage attached. Every change to objects may cause a redraw of html components. So therefore I need to get notified if an object changed.

Comment: this is very tiny and will probably do what you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/observify-js